# What does "weight on results" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms, phrases, prepositional-phrases

I just read the transcrpit from Nightly Business News on NBR.

There is one paragraph I do not quite understand...

> Aggressive discounting, promotional offers weight on results meantime at Lands’ End, the apparel maker reported a nearly $6 million loss as well as the steep decline in sales.

The transcript can be found [here](http://nbr.com/2016/06/01/transcript-nightly-business-report-june-1-2016/).
The NBR video post can be found [here](http://nbr.com/2016/06/01/nightly-business-report-june-1-2016/).
You can listen at [17m35s](https://youtu.be/MA-Zlc9GR8U?t=1055) until 17m39s on the Youtube post.

What is the meaning of "**weight** on results"?

Is "*weight* on results" a correct usage?

Or Should it be "**wait** on result"?

Could anyone kindly give me an answer?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on an online transcription error.

Comment: Yes, the auto-generated transcript from youtube is an online transcription error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, honestly, I think he is saying
"weighed on results" but I am doubting myself.

> [weigh (up)on someone](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/weigh+on)
>   to burden or worry someone

Except here it is *something* not *someone*. He's saying that the discounts and offers made it difficult to get positive results.

---

***Addendum.***
I didn't realize there was a transcript. I think I hear "weighed on" and the transcript says "weight on". I think that is an error. As far as I know, "weight on" isn't an idiom.

Comment: Just listened to it - it comes in at 17:34 and I agree it's 'Weighed' there's an error in the transcript

Comment: Yeah, idk it just sounded strange for some reason. Now that you are confirming it, I hear it clearly. But my brain might be tricking me!

Comment: Click through to YouTube -> More Actions ->Transcript

Comment: The auto-generated transcript of youtube is not that accurate compared to nbr.com.

Comment: @user9418 I wasn't looking at that one. I ignored his comment. I looked at the one located at NBR. I am confident it is a mistake.

Comment: Yes. @probablyme is right. The transcript of this sentence from nbr is wrong. I shound notice that because the same thing happened before. I just make myself clear that's why I did not choose transcript form youtube as a part of my question.